# Using if statement in Oracle triggers

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

1. Table1: customers

   cust_no | cust_credbal | cred_status
2. Table2:customer_credittopup

   cust_no | trans_amount

I have the above two tables, I have written an update trigger after insert into the `Table2` to update `Table1`. Thus the amount in `Table1` `cust_credbal` is updated after adding `cust_credbal` in `Tabl1` + the new value in `trans_amount` in `Table2`. How do i add an if statement after the update to check if `cust_credbal` is > than 20 then `cred_status` is is set to 'VALID' else 'EXHAUSTED'

My trigger showing this error: Error at line 8: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CUST_CREDITBAL'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_insert_credittopup
AFTER INSERT ON customer_credittopup
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  credit number(11);
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
     SET cust_creditbal=cust_creditbal +:new.trans_amount
   WHERE cust_no=:new.cust_no;

  SELECT Cust_creditbal INTO credit 
    FROM customers WHERE cust_no=:new.cust_no;

  IF(:new.cust_creditbal>0) THEN
    UPDATE customers
       SET Cust_credstatus='Valid'
     WHERE cust_no=:new.cust_no;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Which table has 'cust_creditbal' field ? If it's in `customers`, `:new.cust_creditbal` would make sense only inside the trigger on `customers` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that all you need here is just 1 update statement :

```
UPDATE customers
SET cust_creditbal=cust_creditbal +:new.trans_amount,
Cust_credstatus = CASE WHEN cust_creditbal +:new.trans_amount > 0 THEN 'Valid'
 ELSE 'Invalid' 
 --or if you don't want to change status in such case just put 
 --ELSE Cust_credstatus 
 END
 WHERE cust_no=:new.cust_no;
 --SELECT Cust_creditbal INTO credit FROM customers WHERE cust_no=:new.cust_no;
 --IF(:new.cust_creditbal>0) THEN
 --UPDATE customers
 --SET Cust_credstatus='Valid'
 --WHERE cust_no=:new.cust_no;
```

Comment: That worked like a charm for 2 conditions, what if i have 4 conditions such as cust_credbal is > 20 is valid, less than 0 overlimit, equal to zero is exhausted using else if

Comment: You can do it inside `CASE` : for instance `WHEN cust_creditbal +:new.trans_amount >0 THEN 'Valid'  WHEN cust_creditbal +:new.trans_amount <0 THEN 'Overlimit' ELSE 'Exhausted' END `.

Answer (score 0):

`NEW.CUST_CREDITBAL` does not match `cust_credbal`